# How to test video calling with react-native-webrtc

Tags: react-native

I'm following this example https://github.com/jdmg94/react-native-webrtc-example/blob/master/App.js to implement video call. but since only one device at a time can be connected via react native development server, how can I test the process??

Answer (score 2):

We've had luck testing WebRTC apps with automated WebDriver instances at Daily.

https://www.daily.co/blog/how-to-make-a-headless-robot-to-test-webrtc-in-your-daily-app/

Comment: Hi, thanks but the article is not very clear about using it in mobile applications and I'm not sure how to add it to my existing codebase.